# Jquery accordion type functionality only one item open at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have a custom designed grid:

http://jsfiddle.net/97n4K/

when you click a grid item the content div of that item slides open and when you click it again it closes. This works fine.

My problem is i only ever want one content area to open at a time much like a standard accordion.

So for instance i click 'content one' - it opens 'content area one' - now if i click 'content two' i want 'content area one' to close (slideUp) and 'content area two' to open (slideDown) at the same time - just like an accordion does.

Obviously my html is alot different from a standard accordion setup so im stuggling to figure it out how to do it with my limited Jquery knowledge.

Please see my Js Fiddle above - and heres the code if you prefer below:

Thanks

HTML

```
 <div style="width: 100%; height: 68px;">
 <div class="expBtn exBlue ex1"><h3>Content<br>one</h3></div>
 <div class="expBtn exOlive ex2"><h3>Content<br>two</h3></div>
 <div class="expBtn exOrange ex3"><h3>Content<br>three</h3></div>
 </div>

 <div class="expArea expArea1">
 This is content one
 </div>

 <div class="expArea expArea2">
 This is content two
 </div>

 <div class="expArea expArea3">
 This is content three
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .expBtn {
width: 190px;
height: 68px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #000;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
 }
 .expBtn h3 {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #e8e7e4;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1.2em;
letter-spacing: 0em;
padding-top: 13px;
padding-left: 13px;
padding-right: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0;
 }
 .expArea {
 display: none;
 width: 570px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 height: 200px;
 }
```

JS

```
    $(".ex1").click(function () {
        $(".expArea1").slideToggle(1000);
    });
    $(".ex2").click(function () {
        $(".expArea2").slideToggle(1000);
    });
    $(".ex3").click(function () {
        $(".expArea3").slideToggle(1000);
    });

 $(".exBlue").hover(function () {
$(this).css("background-color","#0092d2");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","#000");
 });
 $(".exOlive").hover(function () {
$(this).css("background-color","#9bad2a");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","#000");
 });
 $(".exOrange").hover(function () {
$(this).css("background-color","#ff8a0c");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","#000");
 });
```

Ok so i have created essentially what i want but i have a massive load of duplicate JS that i know could be simplified by any one with better knowledge of jquery / javascript than me. Please check out this new JS fiddle - any solution to get the JS down would be greatly appreiated!

Thanks

NEW JS FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/97n4K/9/

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to keep your same html structure you can use the following to get what you want;

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/97n4K/7/)

Switch your JS click handling to this;

```
$('.expBtn').on('click', function () {
    var area = $(this).index() + 1;
    var new_div = $('.expArea' + area);

    // do nothing if it's already visible
    if (!new_div.is(':visible'))
    {
        // slide up all first
        $('.expArea').slideUp(300);
        new_div.slideDown(1000);
    }
});
```

You can easily add more html sections providing you follow the same numbering you've already done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - please see my new fiddle link with exacty what i want. The JS i have written is really long and im sure could be shorten massively by a JS pro. http://jsfiddle.net/97n4K/9/

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZsCS/ Now it may not be exactly what you want, as I've moved around the html a little bit because the layout looked a little broken and the shorter jquery didn't work using `.index()` with the sections broken up in different places. Additionally, I switched the `:hover` effects to `CSS`. This should give you enough to build upon hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slideUp or slideDown? Im not 100% sure as to what exactly you want to achieve but this fiddle should help you.

```
       $(".ex1").click(function () {
         $(".expArea1").slideToggle(1000);
         $(".expArea2").slideUp(1000);
         $(".expArea3").slideUp(1000);
   });
   $(".ex2").click(function () {
         $(".expArea2").slideToggle(1000);
         $(".expArea1").slideUp(1000);
         $(".expArea3").slideUp(1000);
       });
   $(".ex3").click(function () {
     $(".expArea3").slideToggle(1000);
         $(".expArea2").slideUp(1000);
         $(".expArea1").slideUp(1000);
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/97n4K/5/

Comment: Thanks for your reply - please see my new fiddle link with exacty what i want. The JS i have written is really long and im sure could be shorten massively by a JS pro. http://jsfiddle.net/97n4K/9/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use a plugin for this and it will help better

I have added some simple code so your code can work

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 68px;">
  <div class="expBtn exBlue ex1" data-accord = "expArea1"><h3>Broadcast + Arts + Media</h3></div>
  <div class="expBtn exOlive ex2" data-accord = "expArea2"><h3>Business<br>Services</h3></div>
  <div class="expBtn exOrange ex3" data-accord = "expArea3"><h3>Charity +<br>NFP</h3></div>
  </div>


  <div class="expArea expArea1">
      expArea1 content
  </div>

  <div class="expArea expArea2">
      expArea2 content
  </div>

  <div class="expArea expArea3">
      expArea3 content
  </div>
```

Please look at `data-accord` and it's content

Now for the JS

```
$('.expBtn').click(function(){
        var current = $(this).data('accord');
    $('.expArea').each(function(){
        if($(this).not('.'+current).css('display') == "block")
        {
            $(this).slideToggle(); 
        }

    }); 


    $('.'+current).slideToggle(1000); 
}); 



$(".exBlue").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color","#0092d2");
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","#000");
});
$(".exOlive").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color","#9bad2a");
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","#000");
});
$(".exOrange").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color","#ff8a0c");
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","#000");
});
```

You can see it working

http://jsfiddle.net/97n4K/6/

I hope this can help

Comment: Thanks for your reply - please see my new fiddle link with exacty what i want. The JS i have written is really long and im sure could be shorten massively by a JS pro. http://jsfiddle.net/97n4K/9/